# ECLIPSE E4 - add a typefilter to a PreferenceDialog

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

I have already implemented PreferenceDialog, now I'd like to add a typefilter on the left side.

What is the easiest way?

Thanks

Comment: Please include your code to give your question context. This question is unlikely to generate high quality and useful responses as it currently stands.

Comment: Assuming you are using `org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog` there is no easy way. You would have to duplicate quite a lot of code from `FilteredPreferenceDialog` (which is not available in e4).

Comment: greg is there any alternative to implement something like that?

Comment: @greg-449 I meant to say any alternative to FilteredPreferenceDialog in e4?

Comment: I don't know of anything